# Lines through vertices of $\triangle ABC$ and a point $Q$ meet opposite sides at $M$, $N$, $P$. When is $Q$ the orthocenter of $\triangle MNP$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Consider a point $Q$ inside the $\triangle ABC$ triangle, and $M$, $N$, $P$ the intersections of $\overleftrightarrow{AQ}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BQ}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CQ}$ with respective sides $\overline{BC}$, $\overline{CA}$, $\overline{AB}$.
>
> What are the triangles $\triangle ABC$, respectively, which are the positions of $Q$, for which $Q$ is the intersection of the heights (aka, the orthocenter) in $\triangle MNP$?

I have not been able to solve the problem using synthetic geometry elements. In order to solve the problem with methods of analytical geometry, we considered $A(0, a)$, $B(b, 0)$, $C(c, 0)$, and $Q(m, n)$, where $0<n<a,b<0<c, b<m<c$. We calculated the coordinates of $M$, $N$, $P$ and then we set the conditions that the $\overleftrightarrow{AQ}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BQ}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CQ}$ are perpendicular to $\overline{NP}$, $\overline{PM}$, $\overline{MN}$. But the calculations became complicated, and I quit.

If I could have continued, I would have found three conditions (equalities) that I would have to satisfy $m$ and $n$ simultaneously. It follows that the $\triangle ABC$ triangle must be a particular triangle; and, within this triangle, $Q$ must have a particular position. One such case is the equilateral triangle and $Q$ is its center.

How can triangles be characterized with this property?

Comment: This could be useful to you: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnticevianTriangle.html.

Answer (score 1):

Changing notation a bit, we'll consider a triangle with circumdiameter $1$ and angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. Duplicating OP's configuration with $A$ on the $y$-axis, we can write
$$A = (0,\sin\beta\sin\gamma) \qquad B = (\cos\beta\sin\gamma,0) \qquad C = (-\sin\beta\cos\gamma,0) \tag{1}$$
Now, define our variable point, $P$, using barycentric coordinates: 
$$P = \frac{p A + q B + r C}{p + q + r} \qquad(p, q, r \neq 0) \tag{2}$$
Let $\overleftrightarrow{AP}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BP}$,  $\overleftrightarrow{CP}$ meet  $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$,  $\overleftrightarrow{CA}$,  $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ at $D$, $E$, $F$. We find that
$$
D = \frac{qB+rC}{q+r} \qquad 
E = \frac{rC+pA}{r+p} \qquad
F = \frac{pA+qB}{p+q}
\tag{3}$$
For $P$ to be the orthocenter of $\triangle DEF$, we must have $\overleftrightarrow{AP}\perp\overleftrightarrow{EF}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BP}\perp\overleftrightarrow{FD}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CP}\perp\overleftrightarrow{DE}$, where any two guarantee the third. Considering the last two gives equations that reduce to
$$\begin{align}
(B-P)\cdot(F-D) &= 0 \quad\to\quad 
  \overline{p}^2\left(\overline{q} + \overline{r}\cos\alpha \right)
= \overline{r}^2\left(\overline{q} + \overline{p}\cos\gamma \right)
\tag{4}\\
(C-P)\cdot(D-E) &= 0 \quad\to\quad
  \overline{q}^2 \left(\overline{r} + \overline{p} \cos\beta  \right)
= \overline{p}^2 \left(\overline{r} + \overline{q} \cos\alpha \right)  
 \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
where $\overline{p}:= p/\sin\alpha$, $\overline{q}:=q/\sin\beta$, $\overline{r}:=r/\sin\gamma$.

Using the method of resultants (that is, the `Resultant[]` function in *Mathematica*), we can eliminate $\overline{p}$ from $(4)$ and $(5)$. The relation reduces to

> $$\begin{align}
> 0 
> &= \phantom{2} \overline{q}^4\phantom{\overline{r}^4} \sin^2\beta \\[4pt]
> &+ \phantom{2} \overline{q}^3 \overline{r} \phantom{^4}  \cos\beta  \left(\cos\gamma - \cos\alpha \cos\beta \right) \\[4pt]
> &- 2 \overline{q}^2 \overline{r}^2 \left(1 - \cos\alpha \cos\beta \cos\gamma\right)  \\[4pt]
> &+ \phantom{2}\overline{q}\phantom{^4} \overline{r}^3 \cos\gamma \left(\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\cos\gamma \right) \\[4pt] 
> &+ \phantom{2}\phantom{\overline{q}^4}\overline{r}^4 \sin^2\gamma
> \end{align} \tag{$\star$}$$

To get an orthocenter configuration, we can take $r=1$ (so that $\overline{r}=1/\sin\gamma$), solve $(\star)$ for $\overline{q}$, then return to $(4)$ to solve for $\overline{p}$. These values in turn give $p$ and $q$, which determine the desired $D$, $E$, $F$. $\square$

---

There's no bias in $(\star)$ for isosceles triangles. Indeed, after admittedly scant experimentation, it *appears* that the four roots are valid for any triangle (barring unanticipated degeneracies), and that they correspond to one "internal" orthocenter and three "external" orthocenters (one per side). For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any isosceles triangle can comply with your stated conditions. Consider the sketch below. The positions of $E$ and $F$ can be adjusted between $E_1$ and $E_2$ and $F_1$ and $F_2$ respectively until the lines $BE$ and $AF$ are perpendicular to $DF$ and $DE$.

$EF$ is parallel to $AB$ and symmetry plays a big part in this setup.

[image]

Comment: We have already said that if the *AQ*, *BQ*, *CQ* lines are perpendicular to *NP*, *PM*, *MN* then the *ABC* triangle must be a particular one. Can we prove that under these conditions, the *ABC* triangle is isoscel? And the example given by you supports this supposition.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what you are saying but a summary of the proof for an isosceles triangle is that for a particular point Q along line CD, there is a position of E and F where EF is parallel to AB, where line AF is perpendicular to line ED and line BE is perpendicular to DF. The locations of E and F are between E1 , E2 and F!, F2 which span a continuous range of angles which includes 90 degrees of the aforementioned lines..

Comment: Your example is clear. The question is whether such situations are only in the isosceles triangle, or there are triangles in the non-isosceles.